# Does this code smell?

Tags: java, zip, findbugs

I'm writing some context into ZIP file using [ZipOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html). And I'm using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement for closing the zip stream.

While writing I have to write a String entry content in the ZIP stream. So my code looks this:

```
try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(...)){
    ...
    zos.putNextEntry( new ZipEntry( "fileName.txt" ) );
    String content = "some text content here";
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter( zos ); //(1)
    writer.write( content );
    writer.flush();
    ...
}
```

But FindBugs shows me OS_OPEN_STREAM warning in line (1).

What do you think about it? Does this code smell? Then how to write it better?

Update. 
FindBugs v.3.0.1

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be better suited for this question.

Comment: Related: https://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/bugs/786/

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, this is FindBugs, not IDE message. And the warning is not for try-with-resources but for OutputStreamWriter line.

Comment: @Gendarme, thatks, I didn't know Code Review before.

Comment: I think that the issue here is that FindBugs doesn't distinguish between "a new `AutoCloseable` which opens a stream" and "a new `AutoCloseable` which *wraps* a stream".

Comment: @AndyTurner, thanks for related link. So Is there a way to avoid this FindBug bug?

Comment: is the problem not with closing the OutputStreamWriter rather than with ZipOutputStream?

Comment: @Vijay I shouldn't close OutputStreamWriter because it closes ZipOutputStream then. OutputStreamWriter is just a pipe to write a String into ZipOutputStream.

Comment: Please note Code Review will not like those "`...`", they'd much, **much** rather see your *actual* code, with as much context as possible. Consider reading [a guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788) before posting on CR. Cheers!

Comment: @Mat'sMug, thank's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not FindBugs bug, you don't close the `writer` in the code above, so it complains correctly.
You should do e.g.:

```
try (
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(...);
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter( zos )
){
    ...
    zos.putNextEntry( new ZipEntry( "fileName.txt" ) );
    String content = "some text content here";
    writer.write( content );
    writer.flush();
    ...
}
```

Comment: You're wrong, if I close the inner writer, the outer stream will be closed as well, so no more data can be written to the stream any more. That's wrong.

Comment: You are right, I forgot that Java does it in very non-obvious (mixing responsibilities) way.

Comment: @omickron I've updated the code, now it will behave correctly and should not give FB error.

Comment: Wow, it works! I've forgotten about this syntax! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.

It's a FindBugs bug.

There's a way to avoid it - use IOUtils.write from Apache Commons (commons-io).